# Series Product Proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that :

$$\Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n!}}\Big) \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}}\Big) = 1$$

Well, this is easily seen to be the product of the Power Series for $e^x$ at $x=1$ and $x=-1$ and so $${\frac{e}{e}}=1$$

However I'm wondering how to do this directly from the definition of a product.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{c_n}}\ $$ $$ c_n \; =  \;
  \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{n-k} b_{k}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a_{n-k}b_k = \dfrac{1}{(n-k)!}\cdot \dfrac{(-1)^k}{k!} = \dfrac{1}{n!}\cdot (-1)^k\binom{n}{k} \Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}b_k =  = \dfrac{1}{n!}\cdot (1+ (-1))^n = 0$. Can you continue?

Comment: I reached this conclusion as well but the 0 sort of threw me off and I thought I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Nice. The only term that is non-zero is $a_0 = 1$, and you get the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, good to know I was on the right track.